# When is an infinite series computable?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, computability

A real number is called [computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) if there is an algorithm that computes it up to any desired precision. Suppose $f(x)$ is an elementary function s.t. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ converges (for simplicity let's say absolutely). Must the number $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ be computable?

My understanding is that if we merely assume $f(n)$ to be a computable sequence of computable numbers then there are counterexamples, e.g., [Specker sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specker_sequence). On the other hand, if $f(x)$ is a rational function then this should be true, because we can bound the tail very explicitly. Is there a similar bound for arbitrary elementary functions (or at least some large class of functions)?